# Dropdown option not updating on the front end

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am working with Laravel 5.2. A portion of my form, I have to choose if a user is active or not. I hard coded a default user to be inactive in users table.

```html
$table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
```

Choosing a user to be active or inactive still defaults to Active on the front end. Even though it enters it correctly in my database. Also when I edit the same user, it pulls the correct status from the database. But once I save it, I still get active on the front end. Here's my form

```html
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('is_active','Status:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('is_active',[0=>'inactive',1=>'active'],0,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

I have played around with it replacing the default value 0 with null like this

```html
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('is_active','Status:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('is_active',[0=>'inactive',1=>'active'],null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Still I get the same result.

Heres my table data for front end display.

```html
<td>{{$user->is_active = 0 ? 'Inactive':'Active' }}</td>
```

Comment: Could you also show the relevant controller's code?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the condition operation like this.
replace "=" by "==".

```
<td>{{$user->is_active == 0 ? 'Inactive':'Active' }}</td>
```

Comment: Please reply if this helps you.

Comment: Welcome @olasunkanmi